# Box.com file download using the Java API lib freezes

Tags: java, box-api, box, boxapiv2

I am trying to download a large number of files from a Box.com user account. It works fine most of the time, but sometimes the download just freezes.

This is the call that is stalling:

```
boxClient.getFilesManager().downloadFile(itemId, requestObject);
```

Sometimes it fails after about 20 files, and other times it can go on downloading files for an hour before the freeze happens.

Maybe a timeout setting would solve the problem, but there is no obvious place for that. I tried to add a timeout value to the HTTP headers with no luck. The code looks like this:

```
boxClient = new BoxClient(clientId, clientSecret, null, null, createRestClient(), null);

...

private IBoxRESTClient createRestClient() {
    return new BoxRESTClient() {

        @Override
        public HttpClient getRawHttpClient() {
            HttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();
            HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(params, 10000);
            return new DefaultHttpClient(params);
        }
    };
}
```

Does anybody know why this freeze happens, and maybe how I can investigate it further?

Edit: I am using v3.0.10 of the java lib, which is the latest version right now.

Comment: Can you tell me what is requestObject in this download api?

Comment: boxClient.getFilesManager().downloadFile(itemId, requestObject);